# How to limit result set to only the latest instance in the JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a sales pipeline report, where I capture the wins and losses for for each sales person each week.

The report works for the most part, except for this corner case that bugs me. It wouldn't typically occur, but if a sales person moves an opportunity to a win status, then back to a loss status, then again to a win status - it will count as 2 wins. I am looking for some way to only get the latest row from the audit (detail) table in which (a) the date is within the last week, (b) the after_value is a loss or win or loss value.

I have tried doing this as much as possible in the join, like so:

```
           FROM 
            opportunities o ON ao.opportunity_id=o.id
           LEFT JOIN opportunities_audit oa ON o.id=oa.parent_id 
                AND after_value_string IN ('Loss', 'Win') 
                AND date_created > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
           INNER JOIN sweet.users u ON o.assigned_user_id=u.id
```

but I haven't found a way to use something like MAX(id) in the join. I also tried a MAX(id) in the SELECT, but I have several sum(IF) statements, and I didn't think it made sense to have to do it for every sum(IF) - plus I couldn't figure out how to make it work for just one of them anyway.

I keep going to MAX, or maybe a subquery to join the table to itself and get the MAX(id) that way, but I just haven't figured out where to put the subquery, since I don't want every SELECT to use it. And if that is in fact even the best solution. Oh, AND, the id in these tables look like hash values, so I don't know if MAX would work anyway. Le sigh.

Here's just part of the SELECT, in case it helps:

```
    , sum(IF(o.sales_stage = 'Win'
        AND (o.date_modified > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
            , 1,0))
        AS 'W'
```

I hope I've given enough information, any direction/advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

select Top number|percentage at the beginning from the select